# Adding combobox item to a list of objects and writing to a txt file

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add an combobox value to a list so i can write a selected value to a txt file. This is the function that writes file:

```
public void SaveData(List<Result> results)
    {
        string[] lines = new string[results.Count];
        string docPath = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, 
"Results.txt")))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
                outputFile.WriteLine(line);
        }

    }
```

And this is the button that when clicked, writes file to txt:

```
private void SaveTeam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
        var selectedTeam = ResultBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            results.Add(selectedTeam);
        }

    }
```

but it says i cannot add item to a list since it is not that datatype. How do i convert the value to an object that can be added to a list?

Comment: `List<string> results`? Not `List<Result>`

Comment: yeah that solves it, but i got some cross thread error so nvm :D